# How can I host videos on one server while using the bandwidth of others?

Tags: video, bandwidth, dedicated-hosting, streaming, video-hosting

I have videos hosted on one of my servers, they simple stream from that server direct to users on my webpage using the DivX Web Player. NOTE I can use another player if needs must.

Now I'm reaching the limit on my current connection and need to spread the bandwidth out across my other servers. How do I go about this only hosting the videos on one server and using the bandwidth of others?

Answer (score 1):

If you host videos on on a server, there is no way you can stream those videos from that server without using the bandwidth of that server. However, here are some way that you can try to reduce the bandwidth utilisation:

1. Cache the streamed portions of the video on the client browser. This way, the receiver can replay it without streaming it again, and hence some bandwidth can be saved there.
2. You can host the videos on other servers. There are free websites to help webmasters host videos. You can even host them on Youtube and use their widget to play it through your webpage. That way, the bandwidth of your server is preserved.